# How to set Python path such that it identifies the packages installed in another directory along with initial config?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, pip, path

I need Python to auto detect packages that I installed at a specified directory using *pip.ini* file.
While also keeping the initial site-packages as well.

```
>>>> pip.ini file <<<<
[global]
target = P:\PYTHONPACKAGE
```

**THE ERROR IS -**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 1
----> 1 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

As you can see it fails to detect the packages I installed at that directory.

*As per my basic understanding I need to add or change some configuration in Python folder or maybe edit some Environment variables, but I can't figure out what to do...*

*I use Jupyter notebook using Python 3.11.3 in VsCode*

I don't have enough knowledge to try anything specific, but I did try adding `P:\PYTHONPACKAGE\bin` to environment variables `path`.

PYTHONPACKAGE- The folder I created in another drive to save packages I install using pip as my `C:/` directory is almost full.

Failed though. Doesn't work that way I suppose.

Please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Appending the directory (without /bin) to `PYTHONPATH` should do the trick.

If having it as part of your script is not a problem, you can use

```
import sys
sys.path.append('P:\PYTHONPACKAGE')
```

(which will be doing it temporarily when the script runs), otherwise change the variable directly.